# Does c++ include stl library such as <locale> implicitly from other libraries?

Tags: c++, stl

I am looking at the example given for std::tolower in c++ reference and it seems the method std::tolower works even if I replace library <locale> with <algorithm>

Is <locale> imported indirectly if <algorithm> is included?

Example:

```
// tolower example (C++)
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <locale>         // <-- works for std::locale, std::tolower
#include <algorithm>      // <-- also works for std::tolower

int main ()
{
  std::locale loc;
  std::string str="Test String.\n";
  for (std::string::size_type i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
    std::cout << std::tolower(str[i],loc);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `<algorithm>` from your compiler may or may not include `<locale>`. Even if it does today, it may or may not tomorrow, and it may or may not during leap years. Don't rely on undocumented, unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `<locale>` imported indirectly if `<algorithm>` is included?

There is no import (before [C++20 and `module`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules)) in C++11, just `include`s. Read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (or some newer C++ standard), the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and preprocessor (e.g. [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)).

If you use  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile your C++ code `mathworker.cc` as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -H -c mathworker.cc` and you will see what files are `#include`-d.

On *some* implementations it could happen that `<locale>` gets included.

But if you care about [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) to other C++ compilers (like [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), or a newer version of  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) you should code explicitly the `#include`s documented in e.g. [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: Thanks, 'g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -H -c' is awesome.